# Derivation of the equation of a hyperbolic orbit from the conic section expression derived via the orbit equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

So I'm looking to derive the equation of a hyperbolic orbit from the general expression for a conic section $$r=\frac{l}{e\cos\theta+1}$$ that you get out of solving the orbit equation for an inverse-square potential. Getting the equation of an ellipse ($0<e<1$) is fine. You just convert from polar to cartesian coordinates to obtain the expression $$(1-e^{2})x^2+2elx+y^{2}=l^{2}$$

and then complete the square and do a bit of tidying up to get it in the form

$$\frac{(x-ea)^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$$

where $a=l/(1-e^{2})$ is the semi-major axis and $b=l/\sqrt{1-e^{2}}$ is the semi-minor axis.

To get the equation of a parabolic orbit ($e=0$) is, dare I say, trivial.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the equation of a hyperbolic orbit though, so if anyone could show me how that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: i think you can find the solution here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing $$(1-e^{2})x^2+2elx+y^{2}=l^{2}$$ to
$$y^{2}-[(e^{2}-1)x^2-2elx]=l^{2}$$

then carry on from there, completing the square etc...

Comment: If $e>1$ then $b$ is imaginary and your  ellipse equation becomes a hyperbola.